# Odoo ORM vs SQL

Tags: python, postgresql, orm, odoo, odoo-13

We're having problems accessing records created by the ORM, via direct SQL queries as it seems to be not finding these created records in the DB.

my question is how often does the Odoo ORM commit changes to the Postgres DB?

Comment: To explain it simple: Odoo uses (in normal configurations) workers (threads) for requests for example from the client. After each request without errors there will be a commit. In some special situations you will get commits within such requests. Or another special situation is the mail fetcher, which will commit after each read email.

Comment: Oh and the reason is ofcourse handling errors and rollbacking if something bad happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched and found an anwser on the **Odoo forums**:

Odoo auto commits the changes you make at the end of the transaction, by calling `cr.commit()`.

Although you can call: `cr.commit()` it is not recommended to do so unless you have created your own database cursor explicitly! And the situations where you need to do that are exceptional! and you need to handle error cases and proper rollback, as well as properly close the cursor when you're done with it.

[Never commit the transaction](https://doc.odoo.com/contribute/15_guidelines/coding_guidelines_framework/#never-commit-the-transaction)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of raw SQL queries in Odoo 14:

```
self.env.cr.execute("""
    UPDATE res_users SET active = 'False' WHERE id = 121;
""")

self.env.cr.commit()
```

Make sure you are committing your changes into the database.

Comment: I'm sorry but this has absolutely no relation to the question whatsoever.